# Delphi rebuild modal form at runtime

Tags: forms, delphi, runtime

For example I created a small project as for you to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

I've got a ModalForm that has some buttons on it created at runtime, but when the user presses a " special button" I want all the buttons from the form to be deteled as other buttons will be created on runtime. Here is an example code

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    button : TButton;
begin
    button := TButton.Create(Self);
    button.Parent := Form2;
    button.Caption := 'New Button';
    button.Top := 50;
    button.Left := 200;
    Form2.ShowModal;
end;

end.


unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var

button : TButton;
begin
    Form2.CloseModal;
    button := TButton.Create(Self);
    button.Parent := Form2;
    button.Caption := 'New Button';
    button.Top := 60;
    button.Left := 200;
// Form2.CloseModal;
    Form2.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
      ShowModal;
end;

end.
```

Now in this example I have 3 buttons on the form, when I click on button 1 I want a 4th button to appear. But if I run my code I get the error

"Cannot make a visible window modal"

I read that has something to do with the fact that I don't properly close my Form2.
If I close Form2 and click on the button from Form1 ( same code as the button from Form2) it works and I get my 4th button the Form2.

My question is now, how can I achieve this result I get from clicking on the button from Form1 with clicking on the button from Form2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to close and (re)show a form in order to dynamically add controls to it. In your `TForm2.Button1Click` method get rid of `Form2.CloseModal` and `Form2.ShowModal` calls, ie

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var button : TButton;
begin
    button := TButton.Create(Self);
    button.Parent := Self;
    button.Caption := 'New Button';
    button.Top := 50;
    button.Left := 200;
end;
```

should work.

BTW adding an button to `Form2` in `TForm1.Button1Click()` is just bad design, don't do that (one form shouldn't change other like that). Rather have a method in Form2 which creates the button and then other forms can call that function. Or override the constructor of the Form2 so that it takes an extra parameter which indicates should the special button be visible or not.

To remove buttons you just call `Free` on them. Ie to delete all the buttons on the form

```
for x := ControlCount - 1 downto 0 do begin
   if(Controls[x] is TButton)then Controls[x].Free;
end;
```

But if you have predefined number of buttons it might be better to create them all at design time and then just change the `Visible` property as needed.

Comment: Yes this works, but it doesn't solve my problem entirely as I also have to remove all my buttons from the form, and I have no idea how many buttons I have on the form becouse they are created based on the number of rows from a table in a database.

Comment: I can't do that as some "users" with specific permision can add buttons to the form, so I can't not know where and what buttons to create at design time.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of obvious things wrong with this code.

**Call to ShowModal from the constructor**

The form's `OnCreate` event is fired during construction. At that point it is too early to show the form modally. So you must not call `ShowModal` there. I believe that you should simply remove `TForm2.FormCreate`. The form is shown modally from `TForm1.Button1Click`, and that suffices.

**Spurious calls to `CloseModal` and `ShowModal` from TForm2.Button1Click**

There's no need to call `CloseModal` and `ShowModal` in that method. You can perfectly well create a new button from that method, and there is no need to interfere with the modal loop. That's the cause of your error message. Remove those calls.

**Use of global variable `Form2` rather than `Self`**

Although your form is clearly a single instance form, you should still avoid using the `Form2` global variable from inside `TForm2` methods. At some point in the future you might want to have two instance of the form. Or remove the global variable altogether. Remember that instance methods can use `Self` to refer to the instance. So, for instance, in `TForm2` methods replace

```
button.Parent := Form2;
```

with

```
button.Parent := Self;
```

Likewise, in `TForm2` methods, any time you feel compelled to write `Form2.Foo`, instead write `Foo`.

**Enumerating controls inside another container**

Use the `ControlCount` and `Controls[]` property of `TWinControl` to find all the controls in a container. For instance, if you know the parent of the buttons is the form, use `ControlCount` and `Controls[]` on the form to find its children. Then you can delete any buttons by calling `Free` on those buttons. Test for the control being buttons using `Controls[Index] is TButton`.

```
for Index := ControlCount-1 downto 0 do
  if Controls[Index] is TButton then
    Controls[Index].Free;
```

Note that we enumerate the controls in reverse index order. This trick avoids indexing problems that arise from us modifying the list whilst iterating over it.

Comment: Yes this works, but  it doesn't solve my problem entirely as I also have to remove all my buttons from the form, and I have no idea how many buttons I have on the form becouse they are created based on the number of rows from a table in a database. Also my real project doesn't call the ShowModal from the constructor, these was a quick project made as an small scale example of my app.

Comment: and I thank you for your answer as I learned something new today, but I stated my problem in the first paragrah of the question, nevermind, I will write a new question, as to sadisfy your wish.

Comment: I don't think you really need a new question. Use `ControlCount` and `Controls[]` to walk over the controls inside a container.

Comment: Thank you again! I will do so